# Python: cannot install packages with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I was trying to install a Python package but showed an error as below, I think it might be because I used my company's laptop and it got censored, but I am not sure whether that is the reason, if there are any other possible solutions please help.
Python 3.7
pip 10.0.1

```
(base) C:\>pip install pyvis
Collecting pyvis
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pyvis/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pyvis/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pyvis/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pyvis/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/pyvis/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyvis/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyvis/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyvis (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyvis
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip --trusted-host pypi.org pyvis -vvv
```

Comment: hi @CForce99, thanks for the answer, after I typed first command, it is showing:tensorboard 2.3.0 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.
google-auth 1.22.0 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: how should I get the new setuptools?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools` will do the trick for what I know

Comment: @XaviorL did you try  `--upgrade setuptools`?

Comment: I tried and got same issue:
>pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/setuptools/

Comment: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:

Comment: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/setuptools/ (Caused by SSLE
rror(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping

Comment: tensorboard 2.3.0 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.
google-auth 1.22.0 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.2.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: add this command 
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org setuptools --trusted-host pypi.org

Comment: now it showed another error:  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/hosted-org/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/hosted-org/ (Caused by SS
LError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hosted.org (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for hosted.org

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments try:
`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Then try retry: `pip install pyvis`

Comment: Your answer does not answer the ssl error, the right way to add to an answer is to edit the orignal one.

Comment: For what I know, the ssl error might be caused by pypi rejecting the older version, but you may very well be right.

Comment: You are right but he can't update setuptools becuase of the ssl error.

Comment: Then I think the solution may be to download the files from the setuptools pypi repo and use then manually