# ssl problem after pip request on ubuntu 10

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, pip

I have to work on a Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine and I need to install some packages using pip for a Flask webapp. I keep getting some SSL errors because the version of Ubuntu is too old (I think).
I already try this:

```
--- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py.original
+++ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
@@ -427,6 +427,9 @@
             req = meth(req)

         response = self._open(req, data)
+        if protocol == "http" and response.code == 403 :
+            if isinstance(fullurl, basestring) and fullurl.startswith("http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/") :
+                return    self.open(fullurl.replace("http://", "https://"), data = data, timeout = timeout)

         # post-process response
         meth_name = protocol+"_response"
```

as someone suggested on a old question ([Pip install fails: SSL required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086702/pip-install-fails-ssl-required)). It didn't work (`HTTP Error 403: SSL is required`).
I also tried:

```
pip install xxxx -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

as suggested in [Getting error 403 while installing package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip)
but I receive `<urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:480: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>`.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer is linked to your question: [Python: cannot install packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362454/python-cannot-install-packages-with-pip)
You could try: `pip install xxxx --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org`

Comment: I got  `Usage: /usr/bin/pip install [OPTIONS] PACKAGE_NAMES...
/usr/bin/pip install: error: no such option: --trusted-host
`